# jsplumb - hide connectors when scrolled out of view

Tags: jsplumb

We're hoping to use jsplumb to draw links between items in two parallel, scrollable lists - say, in divs with overflow=auto. If two items are linked, then the list is scrolled so that one of them is scrolled out of view, the part of the jsplumb link that's outside the div is still drawn. Below is an example page (needs a jquery js file and jsplumb js file in the same directory, as per the script includes shown):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.8-all-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {

            $('#leftdiv').scroll(function () {
                jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
            });

            $('#rightdiv').scroll(function () {
                jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
            });

            jsPlumb.importDefaults({
                // default drag options
                DragOptions: { cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 2000 },
                EndpointStyles: [{ fillStyle: '#225588' }, { fillStyle: '#558822'}],
                Endpoints: [["Dot", { radius: 2}], ["Dot", { radius: 2}]]
            });
            var allSourceEndpoints = [], allTargetEndpoints = [];
            var connectorPaintStyle = {
                lineWidth: 2,
                strokeStyle: "#deea18",
                joinstyle: "round"
            },
            // .. and this is the hover style. 
            connectorHoverStyle = {
                lineWidth: 2,
                strokeStyle: "#2e2aF8"
            };
            var sourceEndpoint = {
                endpoint: "Dot",
                paintStyle: { fillStyle: "#225588", radius: 2 },
                isSource: true,
                connector: ["Straight", { stub: 40}],
                connectorStyle: connectorPaintStyle,
                hoverPaintStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
                connectorHoverStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
                dragOptions: {}
            };
            var targetEndpoint = {
                endpoint: "Dot",
                paintStyle: { fillStyle: "#558822", radius: 2 },
                hoverPaintStyle: connectorHoverStyle,
                maxConnections: -1,
                dropOptions: { hoverClass: "hover", activeClass: "active" },
                isTarget: true
            };

            _addEndpoints = function (toId, sourceAnchors, targetAnchors) {
                if (sourceAnchors)
                    for (var i = 0; i < sourceAnchors.length; i++) {
                        var sourceUUID = toId + sourceAnchors[i];
                        allSourceEndpoints.push(jsPlumb.addEndpoint(toId, sourceEndpoint, { anchor: sourceAnchors[i], uuid: sourceUUID }));
                    }
                if (targetAnchors)
                    for (var j = 0; j < targetAnchors.length; j++) {
                        var targetUUID = toId + targetAnchors[j];
                        allTargetEndpoints.push(jsPlumb.addEndpoint(toId, targetEndpoint, { anchor: targetAnchors[j], uuid: targetUUID }));
                    }
            };

            _addEndpoints("plumbleft", ["RightMiddle"]);
            _addEndpoints("plumbright", null, ["LeftMiddle"]);

            jsPlumb.connect({ uuids: ["plumbleftRightMiddle", "plumbrightLeftMiddle"] });


        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 100px">
    </div>
    <table >
        <tr >
            <td >
                <div id="leftdiv" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto; ">
                    Here's some longer text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    <span id="plumbleft">linked</span><br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="rightdiv" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto">
                    Here's some longer text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    <span id="plumbright">linked</span><br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                    Here's some text<br />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

We've tried various z-index tricks to clip/hide the lines (or parts of lines) that shouldn't be shown, but without any luck. Can anyone suggest how to deal with it, or suggest another approach, using jsplumb or otherwise?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

i created a jsFiddle from your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/sporritt/fpbqd/10/

..it is possible to do what you want.  But you have to make that mask div absolutely positioned, which may get tricky in your final UI.  Anyway. It's perhaps a little hacky but it can be done.

Comment: Consider if there is a connection between items of two different tables(draggable). In that case it is not possible to hide connections.